# If else statement loop or repeat until true

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, repeat

I'm not sure how to loop or repeat a `cin >> cashTendered` if the amount tendered is less than the required amount.

So far, this is what I have.

```
if (cashTendered > || == total)
{
cout << "Your change is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << change << ".\n\n"
<< "Have a great day!\n\n\n\n\n";
}
else
{
cout << "You did not tender enough money to cover the total cost.\n"
<< "Please enter amount of cash tendered: $";
}
```

So now I want the if statement to repeat until true.

any suggestions?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling this: `cashTendered > || == total` is a purely symbolic way of saying `cashTendered >= total` ? Hmm....

Comment: Because i'm new and I'm still no 100% of the proper format. I was actually going to put in, `cashTendered == total || cashTendered > total' but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No worries. Learn something new every day. And I have to admit, it is a unique, and totally understandable expression, regardless of the incorrect syntax. *I* knew what you meant because it literally read like a sentence. Just gotta be a little more conforming for the compiler to catch on. =)

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `cashTendered >= total`?

Comment: Omalsa, you are correct. I fixed it though, but thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [loops in c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/). Also if condition can be shortened to `>=` instead of `> || ==`. Moreover, since you want to repeat until the cashTendered is >= total, you need a loop that checks the condition if cashTendered is < total.

```
while (cashTendered < total)
{
  cout << "You did not tender enough money to cover the total cost.\n"
  << "Please enter amount of cash tendered: $";
  cin >> cashTendered;
}
cout << "Your change is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << change << ".\n\n"
<< "Have a great day!\n\n\n\n\n";
```

Comment: Thanks I figured another way to do it thanks to Daler but this answer seems much more simple and logical. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
{
   cin >> cashTendered
   if (cashTendered >= total)
   {
      cout << "Your change is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << change << ".\n\n"
      << "Have a great day!\n\n\n\n\n";
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "You did not tender enough money to cover the total cost.\n"
      << "Please enter amount of cash tendered: $";
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it your way but it still continues on regardless of the true or false condition. Any other suggestions? I have tried switching the if else statements and making the condition less than as well but the program continues even if it recognizes there wasn't enough money tendered.

Comment: I figured it out but it won't let me post the issue so... instead of break at the end of if and before else it should go at the end of else. I also changed it to `cashTendered >= total` and swapped out the statements. Then I added a `con >> cashTendered` and `change = cashTendered - total` at the end of the if statement.